# Exporting a module built by webpack

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

I am writing 3 modules to be published as npm modules

- Admin (has core has a dependency)
- Member (has core has a dependency)
- Core

package.json in Core:

```
{
...
"main":"dist/bundle.js"
}
```

usage of core in Admin:

```
import core from "core"
```

All modules are built by webpack.

The problem is that if I use webpack to build `Core`, generating `bundle.js`, and have `Admin` to import `bundle.js` lots of libraries will be duplicated.

E.g. Angular, bootstrap etc..

What I am doing now is to import the entry file `src/index.js` in `admin`

package.json in Core:

```
{
...
"main":"src/index.js"
}
```

usage of core in Admin:

```
import core from "core"
```

but webpack cannot resolve some dependencies in `core` correctly, for example, I have set up more than one root in `webpack.config.js` in `core` module, so that some short hand import is possible.

```
root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src/directives')
]
// instead of relative path
import "../../myDirective.js" 
// I can use 
import "myDirective.js"; // where myDirective.js is under "src/directives/myDirective.js", but this fails when I try to build `admin` module.
```

Is there a simpler way for webpack to build npm-modules so that it is easy to import?

```
Core: depends on angular, bootstrap, core.js
Admin: depends on angular, bootstrap, admin.js, includes core as a module
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to me too. I suggest it can be done by setting webpack's [library options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

Comment: This isn't an answer, is a suggestion

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I hope it's a correct suggestion.